# Layouts Issue on Different Components?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I'm writing a gui program in which use flow layout to set components.I know this layout start from default center and goes left to right like this
[image]

I also know structure of all other layouts but i want to make a gui like this
[image]

All components in center.But layout use in that picture is null.I only want to know about how can we do that in these type of layout like border,flow etc.

Code :

```
     public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame obj = new JFrame();
        obj.setTitle("My Frame");
        obj.setSize(800, 600);
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Enter Name");
        l1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 21));

        JTextField t1 = new JTextField(20);
        t1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Submit");

        obj.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        obj.add(l1);
        obj.add(t1);
        obj.add(b1);

        obj.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `BoxLayout`. Something like:

```
box.add(label);
box.add(textField);
box.add(button);
box.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

You may have to play with the setAlignmentX(...) property to allow the components to be centered horizontally.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and examples.

Or you could use a `GridBagLayout`. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use GridBagLayout`.